# A rather long question about installation/uninstall

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, uninstall

Ok so here's the deal guys, last week I decided I want to install Ubunutu again because I really missed it. (Last time I had an ubunutu was 7.somehting)
I downloaded 12.04 and isntalled it via bootable usb device. Knowing how dual boots works I cleared up some space on my hard disc before hand using the windows 7 built in disc manager. During Ubunutu's installation I thought that by choosing "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" will automatically just use the space I cleared before, but apperentaly it did not since that partition is still 100% free space.
On what partition is Ubunutu installed when using that method? And how can I uninstall it to re-install it back on the space I cleared up for it?

Thank you very your time reading and helping!

Comment: Hey guys, in disc management I see those partitions:
1. 5 gb(free) /15 (total space) <- recovery
2. 693gb / 770 <- C:\
3. 163gb / 163gb. unnamed
4. 7gb/7gb. unnamed
5. 39mb/39mb. unnamed

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go the disk management in the windows and delete the partition you have made,so that you can regain that space without any uninstalling or reinstalling

Answer (score 0):

well Ubuntu uses different partition file system so windows shouldn't be able to read it it will show up as in the Disk Management .
Right click on my computer --> select Manage -> then disk management --> you will see 3 partition with no name , that's Ubuntu partitions .